# Issue with Python script when trying to parse JSON data from an API endpoint

Tags: python, json, parsing, python-requests

I am facing a problem with a Python script that aims to retrieve and parse JSON data from an API endpoint. I have tried several approaches, but none of them seem to work as expected. I'm seeking help from the community to identify the root cause of the issue and find a solution.

Here's a snippet of the code I've been working on:

```py
import requests
import json

def fetch_data_from_api():
    try:
        url = "https://api.example.com/data"
        response = requests.get(url)
        
        if response.status_code == 200:
            data = response.json()
            # Further processing of data
            return data
        else:
            print("Error: Unable to fetch data from the API")
            return None
    except Exception as e:
        print("An error occurred:", e)
        return None

# Main
if __name__ == "__main__":
    data = fetch_data_from_api()
    if data:
        # Process the retrieved data
        pass
    else:
        print("No data received from the API")
```

When running this script, I encounter various issues such as:

1. `JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line X column Y (char Z)`: This error occurs at times, even though the response status code is 200.
2. `requests.exceptions.RequestException: ConnectionError`: Occasionally, the script fails to establish a connection to the API endpoint, leading to this exception.
3. `AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'json'`: In some cases, the response object does not have the 'json' attribute, although the status code is 200.

I suspect that the problem might be related to the API's response or the way I'm handling the JSON data. However, I've been unable to pinpoint the exact cause.

Any insights into what might be causing these issues and how to resolve them would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you share what the api response looks like? Use curl or postman to manually get it, then verify the response is what you were expecting in the first place.

Comment: I would suggest you look at the data you are getting from the API when you get these errors. print(response.text) & print(data). Then you can work out if the issue is in the data returned, or how u are parsing it. and then ofc compare the data to a succesful run and an unsuccessful one.

Unfortuantely, many APIs will respond with status code 200 even if the response body contains an error.

Comment: @ScottMoore Thanks for the suggestion! I will add `print(response.text)` and `print(data)` to check the API response and parsed data. This should help me identify whether the issue lies in the data returned or in the parsing process. I'll also compare the data from successful and unsuccessful runs to further investigate the problem.

Comment: @PixelLearningMaster About how often do you get the error? 1 out of 10 times? Every time?